# Watch a scope object contains special characters as key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement a filter for AngularJS ng-grid.

[AngularJS Filter Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

[Issue Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindtrue/mttojnt8/1/)

```
function app($scope){
    $scope.filter = {};
    $scope.filter.$ = '';
    $scope.filter.name = '';
    $scope.filter.phone = '';

    $scope.$watch('filter', function(new_value, old_value){
        $scope.filtered = JSON.stringify(new_value);
    }, true);
}
```

**Problem**

Watch works for `name` and `phone` but not for `$`. I am not getting the problem, can someone help me out?

Comment: I can only think that `$` is used extensively by Angular to designate internal objects.  There is most likely a fitler that Angular applies during the `$digest`. `_` works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, you can use whatever property name you like, just make sure it doesn't start with $

Comment: try $scope.filter.$myvar... and update the others after updating the current.... (i think filing you should file a bug to angularjs team)

Comment: the link you provided "AngularJS Filter Example" is not related to your example; and can confuse your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when angular does the dirty-checking to see if the new value is different than the last value, it ignores properties starting with '$':

```
function equals(o1, o2) {
    ...
    for (key in o1) {
        if (key.charAt(0) === '$' || isFunction(o1[key])) continue;
        ...
```

Thus, it will not detect any change if only `$scope.filter.$` has changed and it will not fire the watcher callback.

---

This is an obvious design decision, since properties starting with `$` are considered "angular-specific", but watching a filter-object also seems reasonable.
I would open an issue on GitHub and see what the core team things about it. Maybe they will decide to make an exception for a `$` property or something.